# Python matplolib legend how to reduce distance between frame left edge and markers

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

As question suggests, I'm trying to reduce the distance between the left edge of the legend frame and the markers. [image]

In figure there is the current plot. I would like to find a way to:

1. keeping the `frameon = True` in order to partially mask the underlying points;
2. move markers and labels toward left reducing the distance between legend edge and markers

the actual legend configuration is the follow:

```
leg = ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, 
      fontsize=13, loc=(0.03, 0.01), frameon=True, 
      framealpha=0.5, handletextpad=-0.6, 
      labelspacing=0.08, borderpad=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a negative value for `borderpad`. That will likely cause the legend to move downward as well, so adjust with `borderaxespad`.

Something like this:

```
leg = ax.legend( 
      fontsize=13, loc="lower left", frameon=True, 
      framealpha=1, handletextpad=-0.6, 
      labelspacing=0.08, borderpad=-0.5, borderaxespad=1)
```

Please note that rather than an absolute location, I used `"lower left"` for the legend location. Otherwise the whole "move stuff around with `borderpad` and `borderaxspread`" gets wonky (not a very precise explanation, I know:).

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the following parameter and change the value as per your choice

```
handlelength=1
```

**Example**

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9, 3))
np.random.seed(10)

# WITHOUT handlelength
ax1.plot(np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), 'bo', label='data1')
ax1.plot(np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), 'rs', label='data2')
leg = ax1.legend(fontsize=19, loc=(0.03, 0.01), frameon=True, 
      framealpha=0.5, handletextpad=0.5, 
      labelspacing=0.08, borderpad=0.0)


# WITH handlelength
ax2.plot(np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), 'bo', label='data1')
ax2.plot(np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), 'rs', label='data2')
leg = ax2.legend(fontsize=19, loc=(0.03, 0.01), frameon=True, 
      framealpha=0.5, handletextpad=0.5, 
      labelspacing=0.08, borderpad=0.0, handlelength=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Sheldore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60352511/5446749) and [Sinan Kurmus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60352585/5446749), the solution was combining both your suggestions:

```py
leg = ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, 
      fontsize=13, loc=(0.03, 0.01), frameon=True, 
      framealpha=0.5, handletextpad=0., 
      labelspacing=0.08, borderpad=0.,
      handlelength=1.2, borderaxespad=1)
```

I chose Sinan Kurmus' answer as best to support his rank.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60352238/2) to the question [Python matplolib legend how to reduce distance between frame left edge and markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352238/python-matplolib-legend-how-to-reduce-distance-between-frame-left-edge-and-marke) by the OP [Giuseppe Angora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6837288/giuseppe-angora) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>